# Using redux in a React project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to use Redux in my react project. The objective is to have a component that give me a token. I wan't this token to be stored in my App.js so i use redux. But when i try to save changes to the store, it works but it's not re rendering. Here's my code :

***App.js***

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import LoginApi from './components/LoginApi.js';
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import './App.css';

function pops(state = { sessionToken: '', isLoggedIn: false, group: '' }, action) {
    const { sessionToken, isLoggedIn, group, type } = action;
    switch (type) {
        case 'LOGIN':
            return { sessionToken, isLoggedIn, group };
        case 'LOGOUT':
            return { sessionToken: '', isLoggedIn: false, group: '' };
        default:
            return { sessionToken, isLoggedIn, group };
    }
}
const store = createStore(pops, { sessionToken: '', isLoggedIn: false, group: '', });

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App container-fluid">
                <div className="row text-center">
                    <div className="col-3"><LoginApi store={store} /></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

***LoginApi.js***

```
import React from 'react';
import './LoginApi.css';

class LoginApi extends React.Component {

    handleLogout() {
        this.props.store.dispatch({ type: "LOGOUT"});
    }

    handleLogin() {
        this.props.store.dispatch({ type: "LOGIN", sessionToken, isLoggedIn: true, group });
    }

    render() {
        const { isLoggedIn, sessionToken } = this.props.store.getState();
        console.log(this.props.store.getState());
        return (
            <div className="Login">
                {(isLoggedIn === true && sessionToken !== "") ?
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.handleLogout}>Logout</button>
                    :
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleLogin}>Login</button>
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default LoginApi;
```

handleLogout and handleLogin are calls to my API using axios. I skiped this to be clearer.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a good justification for using Redux. Can you explain what you mean by wanting to store the token in your app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can connect the component to your Redux store using [`connect`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect) from [`react-redux`](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux).

**App.js**

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

// ... rest of code ...

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            // Set up a provider context
            <Provider store={store}>
                <div className="App container-fluid">
                    <div className="row text-center">
                        <div className="col-3"><LoginApi/></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

**LoginApi.js**

```
import React from 'react';
// Import connect
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import './LoginApi.css';

class LoginApi extends React.Component {
    handleLogout() {
        // We get ``dispatch`` through props now
        this.props.dispatch({ type: "LOGOUT"});
    }

    handleLogin() {
        // We get ``dispatch`` through props now
        this.props.dispatch({ type: "LOGIN", sessionToken, isLoggedIn: true, group });
    }

    render() {
        // Access the props here
        const { sessionToken, isLoggedIn } = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="Login">
                {(isLoggedIn === true && sessionToken !== "") ?
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.handleLogout}>Logout</button>
                    :
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleLogin}>Login</button>
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

// This allows you to control how your Redux store
// is mapped to this component's props.
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const { isLoggedIn, sessionToken } = state;

    return {
        sessionToken,
        isLoggedIn,
    };
};

// Wrap your export with connect and pass it mapStateToProps
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LoginApi);
```

This setup will allow you to access the Redux state from any component that you export with `connect` rather than passing `store` directly through props to each component.

Note: you also get `dispatch` through props so the lines `this.props.store.dispatch` can be reduced to `this.props.dispatch`.

Comment: This won't work unless you also set up a `<Provider>` context for the store, which isn't currently happening - the store gets passed in as a prop and then `dispatch` is called directly. Also need to set up the action properly so the action is dispatched properly.

Comment: It depends on `react-redux` version. Some versions had support for passing `store` through `props` without `Provider`.

Comment: @DuncanThacker Yeah I forgot to add that on the first post, cheers for pointing that out.

Comment: Well ! Thank you it worked. Thank you for the tutorial.

Comment: No worries, glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant `default: return state;`. Otherwise any action except 'LOGIN' and 'LOGOUT' will set your login state to something unexpected (usually `undefined`).

To trigger a rerender you need to update props or internal state of the component. You need to `subcribe` to your store and do it manually or use [connect](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#connect).